# Hamcrest: Unclear exception message?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Although English is not my mother tongue, I still think that the following error message from Hamcrest is wrong.

I have the following validation method:

```
private void validateReturnedCode() {

    List<HTTPStatusCodes> expectedStatusCodesList = requestData.getExpectedHttpCodes().getStatusCodes();
    HTTPStatusCodes actualReturnedCode = fromCode(response.getStatusCode());
    assertThat(expectedStatusCodesList, hasItem(actualReturnedCode));
}
```

Suppose expectedStatusCodesList is {REDIRECT_FOUND} and actualReturnedCode is OK.

So obviously there should be an exception here, but I cannot understand the logic of the error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing <OK>
     but: mismatches were: [was <REDIRECT_FOUND>]
```

Wouldn't it be better if it was:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a status code one of <REDIRECT_FOUND>
     but: mismatches were: [value was <OK>]
```

?

The expectation was to receive REDIRECT_FOUND but actually I received OK!

If I get it wrong, could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument for the [`assertThat()`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) method states, that it must be the "actual" value you get:

> **assertThat**
>
> ```
> public static <T> void assertThat(T actual,
>                                   Matcher<? super T> matcher)
> ```

So, your `actualReturnedCode` must be in the front. Use the [`isIn()`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#isIn(java.util.Collection)) match to check if a value is inside a collection:

```
assertThat(actualReturnedCode, isIn(expectedStatusCodesList));
```